# Can Facebook read my calendar on iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook

My iOS calendar is synced with a caldav server. If I set up my Facebook account in the iOS settings to also see Facebook events, can Facebook also *read* my other calendar events?

Answer (score -1):

No facebook wont see your calendar. it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?